# How to substring a string with several position with Perl?

Tags: perl, substring, substr

I have several places where I want to cut my string in several parts.
For example:

```
$string= "AACCAAGTAA";
@cut_places= {0,4, 8 };
```

My `$string` should look like this: `AACC AAGT AA;`
How can I do that?

Comment: Please take a look at [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) to learn about the different types of data in Perl. An array `@foo` is constructed from a _list_, which uses parentheses `()`. The curly braces you used `{}` are for making an anonymous hash reference, which implies key/value pairs. Your code example will not compile.

Comment: @simbabque: It will, but warn under [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings): "Odd number of elements in anonymous hash"

Answer (score 7):

To populate an array, use round parentheses, not curly brackets (they're used for hash references).

One possible way is to use [substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) where the first argument is the position, so you can use the array elements. You just need to compute the length by subtracting the position from the following one; and to be able to compute the last length, you need the length of the whole string, too:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $string = 'AACCAAGTAA';
my @cut_places = (0, 4, 8);

push @cut_places, length $string;
my @parts = map {
    substr $string, $cut_places[$_], $cut_places[$_+1] - $cut_places[$_]
} 0 .. $#cut_places - 1;

say for @parts;
```

If the original array contained lengths instead of positions, the code would  be much easier.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $string = 'AACCAAGTAA';
my @lengths = (4, 4, 2);  # 4, 4, 4 would work, too

my @parts = unpack join("", map "A$_", @lengths), $string;

say for @parts;
```

See [unpack](http://p3rl.org/unpack) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Work out the lengths of needed parts first, then all methods are easier.  Here regex is used

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $string = 'AACCAAGTAA';

my @pos = (0, 4, 8); 

my @lens = do {
    my $prev = shift @pos;
    "$prev", map { my $e = $_ - $prev; $prev = $_; $e } @pos;
};

my $patt = join '', map { '(.{'.$_.'})' } @lens;
my $re = qr/$patt/;

my @parts = grep { /./ } $string =~ /$re(.*)/g;
say for @parts;
```

The lengths `@lens` are computed by subtracting the successive positions, 2-1, 3-2 (etc).  I use `do` merely so that the `@prev` variable, unneeded elsewhere, doesn't "pollute" the rest of the code. 
The `"$prev"` is quoted so that it is evaluated first, before it changes in `map`.

The matches returned by regex are passed through `grep` to filter out empty string(s) due to the `0` position (or whenever successive positions are the same).

This works for position arrays of any lengths, as long as positions are consistent with a string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that starts by calculating the *forward differences* in the list of positions. The length of the string is first appended to the end of the list of it doesn't already span the full string

The differences are then used to build an `unpack` format string, which is used to build the required sequence of substrings.

I have written the functionality as a `do` block, which would be simple to convert to a subroutine if desired.

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $string     = 'AACCAAGTAA';
my @cut_places = ( 0, 4, 8 );

my @parts = do {

    my @places = @cut_places;
    my $len    = length $string;
    push @places, $len unless $places[-1] >= $len;

    my @w    = map { $places[$_]-$places[$_-1] } 1 .. $#places;
    my $patt = join ' ', map { "A$_" } @w;

    unpack $patt, $string;
};

say "@parts";
```

#### output

```
AACC AAGT AA
```